# Что такое статический полиформизм?

Tags: java

Наткнулся на такой термин - "статический полиформизм". Не знал про такое сочетание. В гугле особо ничего не нашел.

Кто бы мог дать обьяснение термина + пример?

Comment: Возможно имлеся в виду [параметрический полиморфизм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC). *В сообществе объектно-ориентированного программирования под термином «полиморфизм» обычно подразумевают наследование, а использование параметрического полиморфизма называют обобщённым программированием, или иногда «статическим полиморфизмом».*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Этим умным словосочетанием обозначают обычную перегрузку методов. Не ту, что имеет место в классах-наследниках, помечаемых словом `override`, а что-то наподобие:

```
class Foo {
    public void some() {
        // какой-то код
    }

    public void some(int parameter) {
        // какой-то код
    }
}
```

Comment: Настолькл всё простл :)))))благодарю

Comment: @elik не буду врать, сам узнал, только загуглив. Говорят, это устаревшее понятие